# WSO2 MI: how to delete registry scope property?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am working with wso2mi-4.1.0. Following this guideline [property-Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-Mediator/) I have created property with scope="registry"

```
<property expression="concat('Hello','world')" name="var1" scope="registry" type="STRING"/>
```

It works fine. I can read that and work with that. Also I can see var1 file in %MI_HOME%\registry\governance. Now I need to delete this registry property. I am trying to do that:

```
 <property name="var1" action="remove" scope="registry" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you please suggest me how to remove registry scope property?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove registry resources with the property mediator. There seems to be no implementation to support this in the [source](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/builtin/PropertyMediator.java#L254).

As a workaround try using the script mediator for this.

```xml
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().delete("gov:/some/path/something.xml");
]]></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. script mediator deletes registry resources but after that it is impossible to do get-property() for that or recreate that - I have NullPointerException.

Comment: Actually what I need is just some variable storage, persistent until runtime restart. I need the possibility to create/update/delete variables here in thread-safe manner. It seems that registry resources creation/deleting is not thread-safe.

Comment: @alxv Yes registry operations are not thread-safe. If your intention is to nullify the value you can update the entry with a null value rather than deleting it. You can use the `update` method for this.